# xml parser - XML xpath compile with condition using Java

Tags: java, xpath, xml-parsing

```
<document-instance system="abc.org" number-of-pages="12" desc="FullDocument" link="A1/fullimage">
<document-instance system="abc.org" number-of-pages="6" desc="Drawing" link="A1/thumbnail">
<document-instance system="abc.org" number-of-pages="1" desc="FirstPage" link="PA/firstpage">
```

from the above xml i want to extract `number-of-pages` count if the desc = `FullDocument`

below are the code
i'm getting the number of pages irrespective of desc value, but i need to include the condition how?

```
String pageCount = "//document-instance/@number-of-pages";
Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(pageCount).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
String url = node.getTextContent();
```

Comment: You need to select the `document-instance` correctly: `//document-instance[@desc="FullDocument"]`.

Comment: you want to retrieve the count ???

Comment: @david : yes to retrieve only that count

Comment: @BoristheSpider :your xpath produce an error

Comment: It's a) not complete and b) needs different syntax for Java (single quotes). It's meant to be a hint as to how to solve your problem, not a copy/pasta solution.

Comment: Ok.  What Boris has suggested will not work for you if you don't put all the path. I answered you. Try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited my answer because you edited your post.

Try it :

```
String pageCountPath = "//document-instance[@desc='FullDocument']/@number-of-pages";
String pageCountValue = (String) xPath.compile(pageCountPath).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

In your case, you don't need to retrieve the node. Get directly the `String` value from the `xpath` evaluation.